# How to implement Viola-Jones algorithm in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, face-detection

I am new in Image Processing and I want to implement Viola-Jones algorithm along with Haar Features for face detection in Matlab. Is there any proper documentation for this?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody did it for you:

- [Viola-Jones Face Detection for Matlab](https://github.com/cheeyi/matlab-viola-jones)
- [Viola Jones Object Detection](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29437-viola-jones-object-detection)

and I guess you can find a few others. A nice description, in pseudo-code, can be found in [An Analysis of the Viola-Jones Face Detection Algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.5201/ipol.2014.104), IPOL, 2014, which you can follow to code your own.